# Duda sobre el dominio de Virtualhost en Apache

Tags: apache, servidor, dominio, virtualhost

Estoy instalando un servidor en una raspberry, tengo un sitio web ya preparado, y está funcionando, es accesible desde internet.

El router está configurado con DDNS, y me redirecciona desde el dominio(subdominio?) `ejemplo.ddns.net` a mi IP y desde el router redirecciona el tráfico al servidor.

Tengo registrado un dominio ejemplo.tk que ahora mismo apunta a `http://ejemplo.ddns.net/ejemplo.tk/index.html`

En el archivo de configuración del sitio tengo puesto:

```
ServerName ejemplo.tk
ServerAlias www.ejemplo.tk
```

El nombre del archivo "ejemplo.tk.conf" y la carpeta del sitio web, "ejemplo.tk/"

Al intentar instalarle un certificado SSL, [certbot](/questions/tagged/certbot) me comunica que no tengo autorización. Sospecho que estoy usando mal los dominios, y que corresponde otro nombre para Servername.

¿En que parte del concepto estoy errando?
¿Que sería una configuración limpia para un caso como el de mi servidor?

Nota: La palabra ejemplo no está usada literalmente, es un comodin del nombre de mi sitio.(Como dicta el sentido común, por si hubiera alguna duda.)

---

**Parcialmente solucionado:**(No he resuelto mi duda de la restricciones y conceptualización fuerte de uso de un "dominio" en un virtualhost de apache.)

He utilizado de Servername el dominio de redireccionamiento `ejemplo.ddns.net`.
Posteriormente de activiar SSL, redireccioné puerto 443 al servidor, y el dominio .tk. Sin más problemas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que el dominio de la web es ejemplo.ddns.net, a menos que ejemplo.tk lo apuntes directamente a tu ip o a tu DDNS. Si tomas la segunda opción, aseugurate que en tu panel de ejemplo.tk puedes añadir el SSL directamente, de lo contrario deberás hacerlo por el servidor web (Apache,Ngix, etc.).

Suerte